# New Blank 2D array without size

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need to create an array for which I do not know the size in advance. I used the following, but it gives an index out of bounds error in my for -loop.

```
string[] arr = s.Split('\n');
int[] indices = new int[arr.Length];

string[][] new_arr = new string[arr.Length][];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i].StartsWith("21")) 
    {
        indices[i] = i;
    }
}

indices = indices.Where(val => val != 0).ToArray(); //contains indices of records beginning with 21

for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length - 1; i++)
{

    new_arr[0][i] = arr[i];
} //first n elements
```

The error is in the second for-loop. It says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But I did instantiate the string at the beginning?

Comment: If you don't know the size, you can use a List<T> instead of an array which will grow on demand

Comment: But this is 1D no?

Comment: It's a [`jagged array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Comment: Yes but with List it will be a 1D list?

Comment: @RicheekDey Yes, you can make an array of lists or a list of lists to make it multi-dimensional

Comment: Ah, but I'm new to C#. hence I wanna keep it simple. Arrays I know. Lists...not really.

Comment: Do you need to  have a multidimensional array? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151970/discussion-between-richeek-dey-and-jakub-dabek).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Looks like you just need a single dimensional array, since you are using only `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize each of the arrays within the jagged array:

```
indices = indices.Where(val => val != 0).ToArray(); //contains indices of records beginning with 21

// create second-level array 
new_arr[0] = new string[indices.Length] ;

for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length - 1; i++)
{
    new_arr[0][i] = arr[i];  // why 0 here?
}
```

Comment: So what I am trying to do is to create a new column (column 0) with the first n elements from a 1D array. I do not know the "n" (it is dynamic) hence I can't hard-code it. The 0 is to access the 0th column ( it is [i][0], i typed that by mistake)

Comment: Regardless, you need to create each sub-array with a fixed size (or use a list and add elements.  I'm not familiar with your process to know what the size of the sub-array should be, though.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2 dimensional array, you will have to specify the size of the first dimension. As I see your code, it is using what is called the jagged array (array containing array as elements) and not a pure 2 dimensional array.

```
var array1 = new int[2,10]; // this is a 2 dimensional array
var array2 = new int[2][]; // this is an array of 2 elements where each element is an `int[]`
```

As you notice, we don't need to specify the size of the inside element `int[]`

Now you understand the jagged array, you can see that you are not initializing the inside element, but simply accessing it - and since it is null by default, you hit the exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length - 1; i++)
{
    new_arr[0][i] = arr[i];
} //first n elements
```

In the code above, you should have `new_arr[i][0] = arr[i]` and also before that line you need to do `new_arr[i] = new int[x]` where `x` is teh size that you want for the inside array.